# Convert the mongoose result into group of arrays

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, handlebars.js

Upon the aggregate function, the output i have got is of the form :-

```
> [ { DescriptionArray:
         [ 'Des1',
           'Des2',
           'Des3',
           'Des4' ],
        PicArray:
         [ 'Pic1.jpeg',
           'Pic2.jpeg',
           'Pic3.jpeg',
           'Pic4.jpeg' ] } ]
```

But, i want the output to be of the form :-

```
>[ { DescriptionArray:
 [ 
  ['Des1'],
   ['Des2'],
   ['Des3'],
   ['Des4' ]
],PicArray:
 [ 
   ['Pic1.jpeg'],
   ['Pic2.jpeg'],
   ['Pic3.jpeg'],
   ['Pic4.jpeg'] 
] } ]
```

The aggregate function of mine is as follows:-

```
>User.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "DescriptionArray": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$services.description",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$concatArrays": [
              "$$this",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }, 
    "PicArray": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$services.badpic",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$concatArrays": [
              "$$this",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
     }
  }
])
```

The schema of my database is as follows:-

```
> var serviceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  description:[String],
  pic:[String]
})
```

Is there any way, i can get the output of my desired format?

Comment: Ok the output you want is not a valid JSON object... So please correct it

Comment: edited now, is this the valid JSON ?

Comment: Now the below answer will work for you

Comment: Again the ouput which you posted in your above comment is not a valid JSON but the output you posted in your question is a valid one and the output of the answer is same as your question expected output

Comment: Okay,  the output must be of the form of [ { DescriptionArray:
 [ 
  ['Des1'],
   ['Des2'],
   ['Des3'],
   ['Des4' ]
],PicArray:
 [ 
   ['Pic1.jpeg'],
   ['Pic2.jpeg'],
   ['Pic3.jpeg'],
   ['Pic4.jpeg'] 
] } ]. But what i am getting is :-[ { DescriptionArray: [ [Array], [Array], [Array], [Array] ],
    PicArray: [ [Array], [Array], [Array], [Array] ] } ]

Comment: You are seeing the output in console... try to console your 0th position data then you can see the original data or see on frontend

Comment: I have actually stored the output in a variable and rendered it to handlebars template, in that i have looped through it in this way:- {{#each output}}
   {{this.DescriptionArray}} {{/each}}. Yet the outcome is not like that of individual arrays, but treating all the values as a part of single array

Comment: Sorry didn't get you but your query has been resolved in the answer...